# Why does the dimension of the input of a LSTMCell must match the number of units

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

When I read TensorFlow's `rnn_cell.py` where `LSTMCell` is implemented, I see the following

```
  def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
    """Run one step of LSTM.

    Args:
      inputs: input Tensor, 2D, batch x num_units.
      state: if `state_is_tuple` is False, this must be a state Tensor,
        `2-D, batch x state_size`.  If `state_is_tuple` is True, this must be a
        tuple of state Tensors, both `2-D`, with column sizes `c_state` and
        `m_state`.
      scope: VariableScope for the created subgraph; defaults to "LSTMCell".

    Returns:
      A tuple containing:
      - A `2-D, [batch x output_dim]`, Tensor representing the output of the
        LSTM after reading `inputs` when previous state was `state`.
        Here output_dim is:
           num_proj if num_proj was set,
           num_units otherwise.
      - Tensor(s) representing the new state of LSTM after reading `inputs` when
        the previous state was `state`.  Same type and shape(s) as `state`.

    Raises:
      ValueError: If input size cannot be inferred from inputs via
        static shape inference.
    """
    num_proj = self._num_units if self._num_proj is None else self._num_proj

    if self._state_is_tuple:
      (c_prev, m_prev) = state
    else:
```

I am wondering why the dimension of `inputs` must match the number of units (`num_units`) of the LSTM. I would expect them to be completely unrelated but somehow they're not.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to match the number of units(i.e. the hidden dimension) of the cell.

First of all:

> num_proj: (optional) int, The output dimensionality for the projection
>           matrices.  If None, no projection is performed.

That's to say, num_proj is the dimentionality of the cell's output which can not match the dimension of the num_units(hidden dimension). Usually the output we want while decoding is of the same dimension of the vocabulary(not the dimension of the hidden dimension or number units here).

```
      if self._num_proj is not None:
        with vs.variable_scope("projection") as proj_scope:
          if self._num_proj_shards is not None:
            proj_scope.set_partitioner(
                partitioned_variables.fixed_size_partitioner(
                    self._num_proj_shards))
          m = _linear(m, self._num_proj, bias=False)
```

As you can see above it just transfer the output(m) to be having num_proj dimension by a _linear projection/transformation. This defaults just to the same as hidden dimension if num_proj is None.

```
def _linear(args, output_size, bias, bias_start=0.0, scope=None):
    """Linear map: sum_i(args[i] * W[i]), where W[i] is a variable.

    Args:
      args: a 2D Tensor or a list of 2D, batch x n, Tensors.
      output_size: int, second dimension of W[i].
      bias: boolean, whether to add a bias term or not.
      bias_start: starting value to initialize the bias; 0 by default.
      scope: VariableScope for the created subgraph; defaults to "Linear".

    Returns:
      A 2D Tensor with shape [batch x output_size] equal to
      sum_i(args[i] * W[i]), where W[i]s are newly created matrices.

    Raises:
      ValueError: if some of the arguments has unspecified or wrong shape.
    """
    if args is None or (isinstance(args, (list, tuple)) and not args):
        raise ValueError("`args` must be specified")
    if not isinstance(args, (list, tuple)):
        args = [args]

    # Calculate the total size of arguments on dimension 1.
    total_arg_size = 0
    shapes = [a.get_shape().as_list() for a in args]
    for shape in shapes:
        if len(shape) != 2:
            raise ValueError("Linear is expecting 2D arguments: %s" % str(shapes))
        if not shape[1]:
            raise ValueError("Linear expects shape[1] of arguments: %s" % str(shapes))
        else:
            total_arg_size += shape[1]

    # Now the computation.
    with tf.variable_scope(scope or "Linear"):
        matrix = tf.get_variable("Matrix", [total_arg_size, output_size])
        if len(args) == 1:
            res = tf.matmul(args[0], matrix)
        else:
            res = tf.matmul(tf.concat(axis=1, values=args), matrix)
        if not bias:
            return res
        bias_term = tf.get_variable("Bias", [output_size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(bias_start))
    return res + bias_term
```